# How to convert Millisecond to date and time using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a record on the database duration field = "3600000", i just want to convert that into date and time, how do i do that?

I've tried this

```
..., SELECT GETDATE(duration) FROM Event ....,
```

and this

```
 ..., SELECT CONVERT(datetime, duration, 101) FROM Event ...,
```

and this

```
..., SELECT CONVERT(datetime, duration, ISO) FROM Event ...,
```

and this

```
..., SELECT CONVERT(datetime, duration) FROM Event ...,
```

ive always get `ERROR on QUERY`

reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp

Comment: Timerange (INTERVAL) cannot be converted to DATETIME. But it can be converted to TIME using [SEC_TO_TIME() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time). Do not forget to convert ms to s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select dateadd (ms,duration,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') FROM Event ...,
```